# How to find unique columns from two table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:
Station:-1,2,3,4    etc...
work:- 2,4,5,6 etc ...

Here i need a query to get unique names from station table comparing with work table.

Comment: Please post what you tried, or at least the table structures. This is not even a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT field FROM Station WHERE field NOT IN (SELECT field FROM work)
```

Comment: There has to be a way to vote against people who does not vote or accept

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct colname from Station where colname IN (SELECT colname FROM work)
```